# Error mounting: mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock after clonezilla image restoration

Tags: mount, hard-drive, backup, restore, clonezilla

Recently, I tried to restore a clonezilla backup of my usb harddisk as the previous one crashed. The old disk is 320GB (about 100Gb in use) and the new one is 1TB

It seems the the image is restored correctly but now the new disk won't mount and gives me the "Error mounting: mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock."

I'm pretty sure my data is there but I cant seem to access it. Can someone help?

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add the output of `fdisk -l` and `fdisk your-image` then `p` to print table